# Three random numbers in a row from specific range of numbers - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am quite new to JavaScript and want to write code, which will display three random numbers from the range 0-6. The problem is, that I also want this three number to be sequential, like for example - 1,2,3 or 3,4,5 and so for. Here's my code:

```
var location1 = 0;
var location2 = 0;
var location3 = 0;

function place_ship(){
var location1 = Math.floor(Match.random() *6);
if (location1 == 0){
var location2 = 1;
var location2 = 2;
}
else if(location1 == 6){
var location2 = 5;
var location2 = 4;
}
else{
    while (var location2 != (location2 != location1 && (location2 = location1 - 1 || location2 = location1 + 1))){
    var location2 = Math.floor(Math.random() *6;
    }
    while((location3 != location1 && location3 != location2) && (((location3 = location2 - 1 || location3 = location2 + 1)) || ((location3 = location1 + 1 || location3 = location1 - 1)))){
    var location3 = Math.floor(Math.random() *6;
    }
}
}

document.write(location1 + location2 + location3);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a row of numbers"? Do the numbers have to be sequential, like you posted (i.e. 1,2,3) or can they be "2, 6, 1"?

Comment: Yes, they should be sequential. I just used wrong wording here.

Comment: In your `else` conditions, you are declaring the same variable twice. The second line will always overwrite the first.

Comment: So please clarify by editing the question. What does "a row of numbers" mean and explain exactly what you want for output. What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the lenght of the ship and the range as factor for the random number. The result is a start position of a ship.

```js
var shipLength = 3,
    range = 6,
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (range - shipLength + 2));
    
console.log(random);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `length` be `shipLength`?

Answer (score 1):

Couldnt you sort the three random numbers?

```
alert([0,0,0].map(num=>Math.floor(Math.random()*6)).sort());
```

That will output sth like:

```
1,4,6
4,5,5
```

If you really want a sequence, you may generate two and put the middle one right into the middle:

```
var num=[0,0,0].map(num=>Math.floor(Math.random()*6)).sort();
num[1]=(num[2]-num[0])/2+num[0];
```

num will be

```
[1, 1.5, 3]
```

Wich is sequential...

If you want a sequence with distance one, you can do:

```
[0,0,0].map(function(el,i){return this+i;},Math.floor(Math.random()*5));
```

Result:

```
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[2,3,4]
```

Comment: I interpreted the question to mean no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can only randomize the first number and then increment it to get the next two numbers.

Comment: Just keep in mind that the "range" will be "max value - length", so that the length can fit within the max value.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to generate one random number and then get the next two numbers that follow it. The random number should actually be no greater than 4 so that you can still display the two numbers that follow it and never go over 6.

```js
// Get the random number. Because of Math.floor, the number
// will never be 5. 4 will be the max.
var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);

// Get the other two numbers and make a string out of them and show the result
console.log([rnd, rnd+1, rnd+2].join(","));
```